# what is the maximum Data storage allowed with flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I need a higher storage but light weighted (portability is more) .. so I prefer flash drive than external hard dist, so that I can carry them in my pocket,

what would be the highest data storage flashdrive that is available in market (example 64 GB? or yet more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can get them in as much as 256 GB (but those are around $700/ea):
[Newegg flash drives](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=522&name=USB-Flash-Drives) (you can check other places, like Amazon, too).